# Is it possible to route traffic through work VPN from another computer? If yes, how?

Tags: networking, vpn

Might been better explain with an example

- **I am working remotely.**
- I have a laptop provided through work. The laptop has both ethernet and wireless connection. I'm currently using wireless to connect to the internet.
- Internal URLs (like our UAT environment) must be access via VPN otherwise the domain won't resolve. (example: If i try to access (via ping,ssh or browser) "uat-internal.myhost.com", it will fail)
- I have a spare desktop which is much more powerful that the laptop and would be great for development.
- If I access internal URLs on my spare desktop, I want to configure it so that the traffic will be routed through the laptop. (I don't mind if all traffic is routed through the laptop as well.)

Any ideas how this can be done? Thanks

Edit:

my work laptop > VPN software > Internet > internal servers

Both devices are currently running windows. But obviously I can change my personal desktop to Linux if that makes things easier.

Comment: Its a VERY bad idea to access work resources with a personal system without permission - if anything gets compromised, its on you, and if its detected, you could be in trouble.. Its a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution will work for your company must be created and
administered by your company's network/VPN administrator.

If the administrator has made your computer accessible via the VPN,
then you wouldn't have needed our help. Evidently that's not the
case, as you say that you can't access it via SSH.

I suggest discussing it with the network/VPN administrator. Hacking the
network is probably not physically possible if the company is
well-enough defended. If you do succeed in finding a hack, you might
also be legally responsible for any harm that arrives.

You absolutely need the cooperation of the network/VPN administrator.
You could explain your need for it as work-related. In our days
teleworking is recognized as necessary.